# Git not waiting for external editor

Tags: git, commit

Using git-2.9.3.el_capitan installed with homebrew. When I do a git commit, git correctly brings up my external editor, which I set up using:

> git config --global core.editor /usr/local/bin/mvim

and that editor is editing the correct file (./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG). However, back in the main shell window, git is immediately giving me an "Aborting commit due to empty commit message," which it prints while the editor is launching!  This has nothing to do with saving the file. Git isn't waiting for me to save the file. Am I doing something wrong? (This used to work!)

Answer (score 2):

`mvim` forks by default, so that you can keep doing stuff in your terminal after it opens. You can pass the `--nofork` option to prevent that from happening; the command to set your editor would then be:

```
git config --global core.editor "/usr/local/bin/mvim --nofork"
```

Comment: That works! However, I needed to use

>  git config --global core.editor "/usr/local/bin/mvim --nofork"

with quotes. Thanks!

Comment: Hey aholub! If my answer helped, don't forget to "approve" it. Thanks!